# How to order a database query

Tags: database

In Drupal v7.22 I'm trying to order the query below for a custom module but I cannot seem to find documentation that fits this query.

```
$sql = "SELECT field1, field2 FROM {tablename} WHERE field3 = :var1 AND field4 = :var2";
$result = db_query($sql, array(':var1' => $var1, ':var2' => $var2));
$num = $result->rowCount();
if ($num != null) {
  foreach($result as $line) {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

I've found details on 'orderBy' but only with examples as below which are not in the same format as my query. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$query->groupBy("thread.sid");
$query->having("MAX(comment.created)");
$query->orderBy("comment.created", "DESC");
$result = $query->execute();
```

Comment: With db_query you need to write query on your own, like you would directly in sql client. That's all. No examples as they are on MySQL / Postgresql sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
$query = db_select('tablename');
$query->fields('tablename', array('field1', 'field2'));
$query->condition('field3', $var1);
$query->condition('field4', $var2);
$query->orderBy('field1', 'DESC');

$result = $query->execute();

foreach($result as $row){
  // Debug
  drupal_set_message('<pre>'.print_r($row,1).'</pre>');
}
```

More info:

- https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7
- https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AorderBy/7

Comment: Thanks. Btw this line caused an error for me `$query->fields('tablename', array('field1, field2'));` and only worked once I changed it to `$query->fields('tablename', array('field1', 'field2'));`

Comment: Thanks glad to hear it. Twas untested, but snippet tweaked to add those missing quotes.